# Initial data and a distributional Grönwall's inequality in the transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, transport-equation

I'm trying to understand the uniqueness result for renormalised solutions to the transport equation. A while back I tried to read the [original](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393835) source but could not get through it. Now I am trying to follow [these notes](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/%20eguether/bibliotheque/BOURBAKI/node4.html).

I typed up a sketch of the bigger problem (First half of Prop 1.6)  but I think its not so important for the point I'm stuck at. You can find it in an [earlier version of this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4564195/3)

The proof eventually leads to a Gronwall inequality, but only *in the sense of distributions*:
$$ f' \le \|\nabla \cdot b\|_{L^\infty} f \quad \text{in } \mathcal D'$$
($b$ is fixed with $b\in L^\infty, \nabla \cdot b\in L^\infty$.) By this I mean, for all test functions $\psi=\psi(t)\ge 0,$
$$  \int_0^\infty f\partial_t\psi + \|\nabla \cdot b\|_{L^\infty} f\psi \ d t \ge 0.$$

In addition, $f(0)=0$ is "obvious" formally in context. However, $f$ is in fact
$$ f(t) =\int_{\mathbb R^n} w^2(t,x)\phi(t,x)\  dx $$
where $w\in L^\infty_{x,t}$ is a distributional solution to the transport equation $w_t + b\cdot\nabla w = 0$ with zero data, and $\phi\ge 0$ is a cutoff (satisfying certain bounds that allow us to reach the Grönwall.) I'm not sure how to rigourously get $f(0)=0$, or in what sense this should hold, because I don't know how $w$ attains the initial data. It is known that $w^2$ is also a distributional solution which might help (this is the renormalization property.)

Why is this enough to conclude that $f\equiv0$?  Even the case $b=0$, i.e. if $f\ge 0$, $f'\le 0$ in $\mathcal D'$, and $f(0)=0$ in some appropriate sense. Can one conclude that $f = 0$? I do know how to solve e.g. $f'=0$ distributionally, and have checked the usual proofs of Grönwall, but was unable to conclude.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: You might want to try to ask this question on https://mathoverflow.net/, too

Comment: @TZakrevskiy a good suggestion, thanks. I don't think its at MO level but might see what they think if I can't figure it out myself (or via an answer...) after a couple more days

Comment: The link to the notes is not working. Also I like the earlier version more, as you left out many details in the edit.

Comment: I think you can use $\psi(t) = h\max( 1-h^{-1}t,0)$, $h>0$, (or a smoothed version) as test function. This would prove $\frac1h\int_0^h -f \ge 0$.

Comment: @daw sorry for the wildly delayed reply, I did see this but I haven't yet found the time to look into this again.